# « Fais-m'en part », avec ou sans tiret ?

Tags: orthographe, trait-d-union, impératif

Je cherche à trouver la manière correcte d'écrire « fais-m'en part ». Je n'ai trouvé aucune mention de l'orthographe correcte sur l'Internet.

Donc, écrit-on « fais-m'en part » (avec un tiret) ou « fais m'en part » (sans tiret) ?

Ça semble tellement bizarre sans tiret, mais une recherche Google semble indiquer « fais m'en part » en préférence (en terme d'occurrences).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La règle à l'impératif est qu'à la forme affirmative les pronoms personnels compléments se placent après le verbe et il faut mettre un tiret entre le verbe et le pronom complément qui suit. Et s'il y a deux pronoms personnels compléments on met aussi un tiret entre les deux pronoms personnels<sup>1</sup>.

Ainsi dans ton exemple :

> Fais-m'en part.

Dans cette phrase il y a deux pronoms personnels tous les deux compléments d'objets indirects. La règle est de mettre *me/moi* avant *en*.
On entend parfois (à éviter absolument à l'écrit) :

> *Fais-moi-z-en part.<sup>2</sup>

S'il n'y avait qu'un seul pronom après le verbe on utiliserait le pronom tonique *moi* :

> Fais-moi part de ta décision.

mais la présence du deuxième pronom personnel *en* (la règle est la même avec *y*) oblige, du moins dans un écrit correct, à l'emploi des pronoms personnels atones (non toniques) *me* et *te*. Et il faut faire l'élision du *e* de *me* et *te*.

> Fais-m'en part.
>
> Prends-t'en.

Voir la [banque de dépannage linguistique du Québec](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4206) pour un exposé complet de l'emploi des pronoms personnels avec l'impératif.

---

<sup>1</sup>

> Donne-la-lui.

Mais

> Fais-lui le dire.

parce que *fais* à un seul complément : *lui*.  *Le* est complément de *dire*.

<sup>2</sup>
Ne pas confondre avec la règle qui veut que quand le pronom placé **après** un verbe du premier groupe à l'impératif est *en* ou *y*, le verbe prend toujours un s à la 2e personne du singulier de façon à faciliter la prononciation :

> Donnes-en à ton frère.

Comment: Merci, exactement ce que je cherchais comme confirmation ! :)